# Record duplication : One Record for a Day

Tags: email, record, checkbox, unique-field

I want to create requirement to create one record for a day. I want to do this through the E-mail field on my custom object. I have checked for "No Duplicate Value" for the email field but want to retain the older functionality such that the same user can create another record again in the next day. How would I achieve this?

Comment: You can create a composite key with date + user I'd and mark it as unique and populate it on record creation

Comment: @manjit5190 how would i create a composite key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Create a text field with **Unique checkbox true**
- Create a workflow rule with no criteria and use field update options.
- In field update select the field which you have created (Unique text
  field) in the first step.
- Use a formula to update that field value  with Concatenation of Date,
  LoggedinUser, Email Id (**Formula:**
  *TEXT(Today())&""&LoggedinUserId&""&Email__c* )
  Hope this will solve your issue :)

Comment: How would I create a No criteria workflow? I'm facing problem with Serial No. The record gets a count even when its not created. Please provide me with a resolution.

Comment: select third option created and edited subsequently meet criteria and in formula just write true

Comment: Done that, but got the same result. Do share some other resolution if possible.

Comment: what issue you are facing

Comment: I'm facing problem with the auto-generated serial number which gets displayed after every record is created. A new count is added to the serial number even for an unsuccessful record creation (for duplicate record). I don't want this to happen. I want a valid count for a valid record.

Comment: Without inserting how your serial no is updated that serial number field is auto number field or you have written any custom logic there

Comment: Its an auto number field. No logic has been used there.

Comment: duplicate records are still creating or its showing error

Comment: Not getting created. Shows error.

Comment: I think then autonumber will not update

Comment: That should be the scenario but acting antagonistically. Is there any resolution for this?

Comment: As per my understanding, this will never happen If it is so then you can add validation through trigger on before insert. But I repeate auto-number will never updated without creating the record